# How to install AWS CLI through PowerShell script?

Tags: powershell, aws-cli

I am trying to check if aws cli is installed already, and install it if not present, I can't find any source on how to install it through PowerShell script

```
function prereq {
    if ((Get-Command aws -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $null) {
        Write-Host "Unable to find aws.exe in your PATH."
    } else {
    # Download from this link https://awscli.amazonaws.com/AWSCLIV2.msi
    # Install the AWSCLIV2.msi 
    # print aws cli version "aws --version"
    }
}

prereq
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some research I was able to find a solution:

```
function prereq {
    if ((Get-Command aws -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $null) {
        Write-Host "Unable to find aws.exe in your PATH."
    } else {
        $command = "[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12"
        Invoke-Expression $command
        Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://awscli.amazonaws.com/AWSCLIV2.msi" -Outfile C:\AWSCLIV2.msi
        $arguments = "/i `"C:\AWSCLIV2.msi`" /quiet"
        Start-Process msiexec.exe -ArgumentList $arguments -Wait
    }
}

prereq
```

Comment: after start-process you need to update the path so that aws --version command will work,   add this command:   `$env:Path = [System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("Path","Machine")`   see reference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62973120/powershell-does-not-recognize-aws-cli-installed-in-the-same-script)

Answer (score 4):

If you are using PowerShell 7, you can easily install it using the Windows Project Manager(WINGET). Use following command >

```
winget install --id "Amazon.AWSCLI"
```

You can also look for it and other AWS utilites using the following command >

```
winget search --name "aws"
```

[Screenshot of the Shell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M2sD3.png)