# PowerShell does not recognize AWS CLI installed in the same script

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell

I have installed aws cli using powershell script

```
 $command = "[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12"
 Invoke-Expression $command
 Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://awscli.amazonaws.com/AWSCLIV2.msi" -Outfile C:\AWSCLIV2.msi
 $arguments = "/i `"C:\AWSCLIV2.msi`" /quiet"
 Start-Process msiexec.exe -ArgumentList $arguments -Wait
 aws --version
```

When I try to print the `aws --version` it gives the below error.

```
aws : The term 'aws' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, 
script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path 
was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ aws
+ ~~~
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I was able to fix this by adding the below line after installing aws cli:

```
$env:Path = [System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("Path","Machine")
```

complete code:

```
$command = "[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12"
Invoke-Expression $command
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://awscli.amazonaws.com/AWSCLIV2.msi" -Outfile C:\AWSCLIV2.msi
$arguments = "/i `"C:\AWSCLIV2.msi`" /quiet"
Start-Process msiexec.exe -ArgumentList $arguments -Wait
$env:Path = [System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("Path","Machine")
aws --version
aws s3 ls
```

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue on my **Windows** OS, after installing the **.msi file** from the [aws official website](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/getting-started-install.html).
it is now solved by just passing the **PATH** of installed aws cli `AWSCLIV2` to the `system environment variable` which is by default for me is `C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSCLIV2` you can do the same but if you customized the path while installation then use yours.