# Docker in Docker and AWS CLI for Windows Containers

Tags: docker, aws-cli, aws-codebuild

I'm trying to migrate .NET legacy application to AWS ECS/Fargate. I'm following this [article](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/extending-aws-codebuild-with-custom-build-environments-for-the-net-framework/) that explains how to create a custom Windows Docker image with MSBuild tools used in AWS CodePipeline/CodeBuild project. I also need to be able to install a Docker deamon and AWS CLIV2 into that custom image so that I could execute docker and AWS CLI commands in buildspec.yaml file in CodeBuild. So far I've been able to use [this code](https://github.com/docker-library/docker/blob/034e1d03eaf2c35ce4a21c4a4b621e2d2174b62e/20.10/windows/windowsservercore-ltsc2022/Dockerfile) in my custom image Dockerfile which installs [Docker in Docker](https://hub.docker.com/_/docker/) but the Docker service never gets started even though it understands docker --version command. I was also trying to modify [this PowerShell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62973120/powershell-does-not-recognize-aws-cli-installed-in-the-same-script) to install AWS CLI but also stuck with having little to no progress.

I'd appreciate any help in installing Docker in Docker and AWS CLI.

Answer (score 0):

When I had to use docker in docker, I instead used the host docker socket by mounting that in the container.

I had to mount 2 files in linux.

```
/usr/bin/docker (executable)
/var/run/docker.sock (service socket)
```

Update - Above would work for linux, for windows, a double slash is required. Below socket would have to be mounted for windows. I couldn't personally test as I don't have windows.

```
"\\.\pipe\docker_engine:\\.\pipe\docker_engine"
```

I found a very good GUI tool explained this
[image]

Ref: https://tomgregory.com/running-docker-in-docker-on-windows/

Comment: Hi iArc, this might work for Linux based containers. I'm looking to use Windows based ones.

Comment: Hey, @GGG try this for windows instead `"\\.\pipe\docker_engine:\\.\pipe\docker_engine"` I think windows would double `\\`, adding in the answer as well.